# Haskell install and use packages

Tags: haskell, distributed

I want to use in my haskell project xml library (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml)

I downloaded it.then try to build and install:

```
runhaskell Setup.hs configure

runhaskell Setup.hs build

runhaskell Setup.hs install
```

All ok. There are no errors. When i try import modules from this lib to my project, for example:

```
import Text.XML.Light.Cursor
```

I get error:

```
/home/shk/dev/src/XMPP.hs:8:8:
    Could not find module `Text.XML.Light.Cursor':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What's wrong? How can i install and use library in haskell?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you building your project? Are you using cabal, or directly invoking ghc?

Comment: You really want to use cabal or cabal-dev.  Calling ghc directly will lead to frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the mailing list:

First thing is to do 'ghc-pkg list'.  If your package doesn't show up
then it's not installed, according to the package registry.  'cabal
install' should have registered it.  If it is in the list, then it
depends how you're building.  If you use ghc manually, then you have
to give '-package xyz'.  If you use 'ghc --make', ghc will
automatically add the -package for you.  If you use cabal, you put the
package in the dependencies, and 'cabal build' will add -package for
you.

If the package has parens, then someone hid it, and you'll have to do
'ghc-pkg expose' on it.  If you're doing everything else right and it
still doesn't find the package, then you can run ghc -v and it'll
print lots of details.  It might have something about 'hiding xyz
because of ', which means you're depending on
libraries that expect different versions of the underlying library.
You can sometimes get out of this by carefully upgrading or
downgrading certain libraries.